# Updating a cell based with the value that came before it

Tags: python, matrix, attributes, cursor

I want to develop a script to update individual cells (row of a specific column) of an attribute table based on the value of the cell that comes immediately before it as well as data in other columns but in the same row. I'm sure that this can be done with cursors but I'm having trouble conceptualizing exactly how to tackle this.

Essentially what I want to do is this:

If Column A, row 13 = a certain value AND Column B, row 13 = a certain value (but different from A), then change Column A, row 13 to be the same value as Column A, row 12.

If this can't be done with cursors then maybe some kind of array or matrix, or list of lists would be the way to go? I'm basically looking for the best direction to take with this. EDIT: My files are shapefiles or I also have them in .csv format. My code is really basic right now:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/All Data Files/My Documents All/My Documents/wrk"


inputLyr = "C:/All Data Files/My Documents All/My Documents/wrk/file.lyr"

fields = ["time", "lon", "activityIn", "time", "fixType"]

cursor180 = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputLyr, fields, """"lon" = -180""")
for row in cursor180:
    # Print the rows that have no data, along with activity Intensity
    print row[0], row[1], row[2]
```

Comment: In what format/file do you have your data?

Comment: you need to show us some code, what you are using, etc. to do this. It's not a difficult problem, but it's hard to answer in the abstract.

Comment: Thank you so far for your responses. I have the files in both shapefile and .csv format. So far I've only created a cursor to return the values from the rows that I need (code is below) but I wanted to make sure that my framework was right before delving too far in any one direction.